# How to lock every channel of a guild with a command?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making a lockdown command to lock every channel (so members with the `member` role can't send messages in any channel). My code is locking only the channel the command was used in, instead of every channel. How do I fix this?

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
async def lockdown(ctx):
  all_channels = ctx.guild.channels
  role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=member_role_id)
  everyone = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=everyone_role_id)
  for channel in all_channels:
    await ctx.channel.set_permissions(role, send_messages=False)
  channel = client.get_channel(bulletin_chan_id)
  await channel.send(f"{everyone.mention} {lockdown_message}")
```

Comment: Weird. I clicked "Improve Edit" in the review queue but it ended up rejecting it for some reason.

Comment: @EricJin, I guess [the OP rejected it.](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/32418298) I didn't read it properly, so proposed the wrong edit. Sorry for that. Thanks for editing it to remove the tags and add syntax highlighting for the code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the permissions of `ctx.channel` for every loop, instead of the channels that you're iterating over.

```py
for channel in all_channels:
    await channel.set_permissions(role, send_messages=False)
```

Also, rather than `everyone = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=everyone_role_id)`, you can simply use `ctx.guild.default_role` for the "@everyone" role.